# How can I run Tensorboard on a remote server?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, data-visualization, remote-access, tensorboard

I'm new to Tensorflow and would greatly benefit from some visualizations of what I'm doing. I understand that Tensorboard is a useful visualization tool, but how do I run it on my remote Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Some possible solutions: (1) It might be the same as running on a local machine, although I haven't verified this: after you run it, it provides you a port number, with that you access it from the browser on your local machine.
(2) Are you able to use remote desktop software such as RealVNC?
(3) I assume you also run tensorflow computations on the same remote machine; you can also download the log files to your local machine, and run tensorboard on your local machine.

Answer (score 322):

Here is what I do to avoid the issues of making the remote server accept your local external IP:

- when I ssh into the machine, I use the option `-L` to transfer the port `6006` of the remote server into the port `16006` of my machine (for instance):

  `ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 olivier@my_server_ip`

What it does is that everything on the port `6006` of the server (in `127.0.0.1:6006`) will be **forwarded** to my machine on the port `16006`.

---

- You can then launch tensorboard on the remote machine using a standard `tensorboard --logdir log` with the default `6006`port
- On your local machine, go to http://127.0.0.1:16006 and enjoy your remote TensorBoard.

Comment: Also had an issue with tensorboard plots being all black on Safari, it works on Chrome (related to issue [#4856](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4856))

Comment: A small hint: `127.0.0.1` here is your **local** machine ip, so you should leave it as is. Do not change it to your remote ip. I wasted 10 minutes on this. How stupid I am!

Comment: this and enforcing IPv4 with the `-4` ssh flag solved it. Reading around similar questions, many have had issues with IPv6 addresses in their servers.

Comment: It seems like I have to stay in the ssh shell. If I close the ssh shell, there is no response from the remote tensorboard. Is there a way to be still connected to the tensorboard while shutting down the ssh shell?

Comment: @Fan: check the other answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42445070/5098368). Basically you can add the `-N` flag to avoid opening an ssh shell. Adding `-f` puts the ssh connection in the background.

Comment: as mentioned by @0xcaff, you should listen on your other interfaces instead

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Thank you for this answer. How do you use TensorBoard + Jupyter + SSH? Do you basically need to do the same as your answer for Jupyter as well? Does this mean you require two `-L port:ip:port` port redirections, one for Tensorboard, one for Jupyter?

Comment: @Basj: you can also add the port forwarding to your `.ssh/config`. But yes you need one port for each.

Comment: Hi, what should go in place of olivier?

Answer (score 162):

You can port-forward with another `ssh` command that need not be tied to how you are connecting to the server (as an alternative to the other answer). Thus, the ordering of the below steps is arbitrary.

1. from your **local** machine, run

   `ssh -N -f -L localhost:16006:localhost:6006 <user@remote>`
2. on the **remote** machine, run:

   `tensorboard --logdir <path> --port 6006`
3. Then, navigate to (in this example) http://localhost:16006 on your local machine.

(explanation of ssh command:

`-N` : no remote commands

`-f` : put ssh in the background

`-L <machine1>:<portA>:<machine2>:<portB>` :

forward `<machine1>:<portA>` (local scope) to `<machine2>:<portB>` (remote scope)

Comment: as mentioned by @0xcaff, you should listen on your other interfaces instead

Comment: For specific port, ssh -p PORTNUMBER -N -f -L localhost:16006:localhost:6006 <user@remote>.

Comment: According to the 'man ssh' page, the -L option does port forwarding FROM the local scope TO the remote scope. But otherwise great answer.

Comment: @BonRyu you're right, thanks! I've fixed the answer

Comment: May I ask how to shut down this link？Thanks

Comment: What is 'user' in first step and 'path' in third?

Answer (score 139):

You don't need to do anything fancy. Just run:

```
tensorboard --host 0.0.0.0 <other args here>
```

and connect with your server url and port. The `--host 0.0.0.0` tells tensorflow to listen from connections on all IPv4 addresses on the local machine.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.. mostly likely tensorboard is just not bound to an address visible to external services.

Comment: It doesn't work for me for a remote server...What am I missing?

Comment: If you only want to listen on your public IP, you can do:
    tensorboard --host $(hostname -I) <other args here>

And then you can copy-paste the URL that tensorboard prints out:
TensorBoard 1.12.2 at http://10.0.50.42:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Comment: @Idanazuri Do you have http access to your remote machine, or is it firewalled (eg: only accessible via an ssh connection)? If it's ssh only, then this answer will not work for you.

Comment: This answer is particularly relevant to a situation where you trained on a system on your private LAN and just want to do an ad hoc examination of the training process. You will need to specify your logdir (you'll likely find that as a subdir of your checkpoint directory, with a file that looks something like "events.out.tfevents.1604862122.blah.blah.blah")

Comment: Straightforward but works like a magic!

Answer (score 28):

Another option if you can't get it working for some reason is to simply mount a logdir directory on your filesystem with sshfs:

`sshfs user@host:/home/user/project/summary_logs ~/summary_logs`

and then run Tensorboard locally.

Answer (score 21):

`--bind_all` option is useful.

```
$ tensorboard --logdir runs --bind_all
```

The port will be automatically selected from 6006 incrementally.(6006, 6007, 6008... )

Answer (score 15):

You can directly run the following command on terminal of your remote server to run tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --logdir {tf_log directory path} --host "0.0.0.0" --port 6006
```

Or you can also start the tensorboard within your ipython notebook:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir {tf_log directory path} --host "0.0.0.0" --port 6006
```

Comment: what means "0.0.0.0" , do I need to replace it with something else?

Comment: Its your local machine's port, you can change it if you have different host

Comment: This worked for me.  I was using VSCode to remote connect to a machine.  In the VSCode terminal of the remote machine I entered the exact command in this answer.  VSCode prompted me to open in a browser ( I was using Microsoft Edge), which I did, and Tensorboard showed up

Answer (score 12):

1. Find your *local* external IP by googling `"whats my ip"` or entering this command: `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -`
2. Determine your *remote* external IP.  This is probably what comes after your username when ssh-ing into the remote server.  You can also `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -` again from there too.
3. Secure your remote server traffic to just accept your *local* external IP address
4. Run Tensorboard.  Note the port it defaults to: `6006`
5. Enter your *remote* external IP address into your browser, followed by the port: `123.123.12.32:6006`

If your remote server is open to traffic from your local IP address, you should be able to see your remote Tensorboard.

**Warning**: if **all** internet traffic can access your system (if you haven't specified a single IP address that can access it), anyone may be able to view your TensorBoard results and runaway with creating SkyNet themselves.

Answer (score 9):

You have to create a ssh connection using port forwarding:

```
ssh -L 16006:127.0.0.1:6006 user@host
```

Then you run the `tensorboard` command:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/logs
```

Then you can easily access the `tensorboard` in your browser under:

```
localhost:16006/
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not a proper answer but a troubleshooter, hopefully helps other less seasoned networkers like me.

In my case (firefox+ubuntu16) the browser was connecting, but showing a blank page (with the tensorboard logo on the tab), and no log activity at all was shown. I still don't know what could be the reason for that (didn't look much into it but if anybody knows please let know!), but I solved it switching to ubuntu's default browser. Here the exact steps, pretty much the same as in @Olivier Moindrot's answer:

1. On the server, start tensorboard: `tensorboard --logdir=. --host=localhost --port=6006`
2. On the client, open the ssh tunnel `ssh -p 23 <USER>@<SERVER> -N -f -L localhost:16006:localhost:6006`
3. Open ubuntu's `Browser` and visit `localhost:16006`. The tensorboard page should load without much delay.

---

To check that the SSH tunnel is effectively working, a simple echo server like [this python script](https://gist.github.com/solusipse/6419144) can help:

1. Put the script into an `<ECHO>.py` file in the server and run it with `python <ECHO>.py`. Now the server will have the echo script listening on [0.0.0.0:5555](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1).
2. On the client, open the ssh tunnel `ssh -p <SSH_PORT> <USER>@<SERVER> -N -f -L localhost:12345:localhost:5555`
3. On the client, in the same terminal used to open the tunnel (step 2.), issuing `telnet localhost 12345` will connect to the echo script running in the server. Typing `hello` and pressing enter should print `hello` back. If that is the case, your SSH tunnel is working. This was my case, and lead me to the conclusion that the problem involved the browser. Trying to connect from a different terminal caused the terminal to freeze.

As I said, hope it helps!
Cheers,
Andres

Comment: I have the exact same problem on chromium+ubuntu14, even worse, it works perfectly fine for the port forwarded from one computer, but shows the same blank page (with correct favicon) for another. Firefox works just fine. Still didn't figure it out, just using firefox now.

Comment: Yeah, many factors involved but as long as it works... another thing to note is that the TB version that comes with TF is different from the TB-standalone one that can be found here... `https://github.com/dmlc/tensorboard` just to add more alternatives to the setup. Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to use a *reverse proxy*, which allows you to **view Tensorboard from any internet connected device without SSHing**. This approach can make it far easier / tractable to view Tensorboard on mobile devices, for example.

Steps:

1) Download reverse proxy Ngrok on your remote machine hosting Tensorboard. See https://ngrok.com/download for instructions (~5 minute setup).

2) Run `ngrok http 6006` (assuming you're hosting Tensorboard on port 6006)

3) Save the URL that ngrok outputs:

[image]

4) Enter that into any browser to view TensorBoard:

[image]

Special thanks to [Sam Kirkiles](https://medium.com/samkirkiles/access-tensorboard-on-your-phone-from-anywhere-6c2eb7fa673e)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who must use the ssh keys (for a corporate server).

Just add `-i /.ssh/id_rsa` at the end.

`$ ssh -N -f -L localhost:8211:localhost:6007 myname@servername -i /.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 1):

While running the tensorboard give one more option --host=**ip of your system** and then you can access it from other system using http://**ip of your host system**:6006

Answer (score 0):

For who like me using Pytorch and and connect to a remote server via ssh and want to try tensorboard in vscode :

. Install the **Tensorboard Extension**
. Open the command palette and select the command **Python: Launch Tensorboard**
Afterwards, you'll be prompted to select the folder where your TensorBoard log
files are located.

for me this worked.