# save a TensorBoard session as HTML including all graphs and images

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tensorflow, save, tensorboard

I'm using TensorBoard to visualize some scalar data (accuracy, loss and such) as well as some confusion matrices as png images generated with matplotlib.

It is running on a remote server, and since it doesn't serve HTTP, I'm able to view the TensorBoard session via an SSH tunnel as I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45024736/4511978).

Now, **I would like to save the whole interactive page in a way that it can be opened and fully explored with the web browser without having TensorBoard installed, or any internet connection**. The contents of the page should be the ones present in the session at the moment of saving.

Is that possible? I tried with the obvious `Ctrl+S`, and some basic `wget` variants without success... the graphs and some images are missing, and the tabs don't work as expected. any help is much appreciated!

---

**EDIT**: just found about [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074688/how-do-you-read-tensorboard-files-programmatically), it seems closely related
**EDIT 2**: the recently released [plugin API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example), may also provide functionality for that

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into the recently released [plugin API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard-plugin-example), it looks promising... will post if I experience any progress